# how to change background color

Tags: c++, glut

I want to change background color of the window after pressing the RIGHT_BUTTON
but it don't work .

```
#include <glut.h>
#define RED 1
#define GREEN 2
#define BLUE 3
#define WHITE 4
#define BLACK 5
double re=0.0,ge=0.0,bl=0.0,al=0.0;
double anglex=0.0,angley=0.0;
double r=0.0,g=0.0,b=0.0;

void mydisplay(void)
{   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(r,g,b);
    glutSolidTeapot(400);
        glEnd();
    glFlush();}

void Objectcolor (int k) {
 r=0.0,g=0.0,b=0.0;
 switch (k){
 case 1: {r= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();
          break;}
 case  2: {g= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();break;}
 case 3 :{b= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();break;}
 case   4 : {r=1.0,g= 1.0,b=1.0; 
     glutPostRedisplay();break;
            }case   5: {r=0.0,g= 0.0,b=0.0; 
     glutPostRedisplay();break;}}}

void asd()
{int q =glutCreateMenu(Objectcolor);
glutAddMenuEntry("Red",RED);
glutAddMenuEntry("Green",GREEN);
glutAddMenuEntry("Blue",BLUE);
glutAddMenuEntry("white",WHITE);
glutAddMenuEntry("black",BLACK);
}



void Backgroundcolor(int k) {

switch (k){
case 1: {re= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();    break;}
case 2:{ge= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();    break;}
case 3: {bl= 1.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();    break;}
case  4: {re=1.0,ge= 1.0,bl=1.0,al=0.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();    break;}
case 5: {re=0.0,bl= 0.0,ge=0.0,al=0.0; 
glutPostRedisplay();    break;}}}

void back()
{int s =glutCreateMenu(Backgroundcolor);
glutAddMenuEntry("Red",1);
glutAddMenuEntry("Green",2);
glutAddMenuEntry("Blue",3);
glutAddMenuEntry("white",4);
glutAddMenuEntry("black",5);
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);}







    void main (int argc,char ** argv)

{
glutInit(& argc , argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(800,640);
glutCreateWindow("MY FIRST PROG");
glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
glClearColor(re,ge,bl,al);
glPointSize(4.0);
glOrtho(-800.0,800.0,-640.0,640.0,-1000.0,1000.0);
back();
glutMainLoop();}
```

Comment: Die you consider the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Use `glClearColor` to set the background color. In your code, you only set it once in `main()` but don't change it anywhere else, so it never changes. You need to call `glClearColor` when you want it to change.

Comment: Wording was confusing, I wasn't commanding them that they should only set it once, I was stating that the OP was only setting it once and therefore it wasn't changing. I'll edit

Comment: I am very grateful

Comment: I want to make it sub menu but it don't work  http://textuploader.com/5bkzg       this is the problem https://i.imgsafe.org/0e7b771.png

Comment: That's a different problem than what this question asks. post a new question.